# How to display selected value outside to uib-tab

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have Bootstrap Ui tabs,that is load values from Array object in a controller.
This is what i'm trying to do.
when user click on the tab,i want to display the value on DIV (out side the uib-tab) and it should be come from controller.

Currently it is work in side the uib-tab and display value in bottom.but i want it to display on right side .I'm new to AngularJs.

index.html

```
<div class="row grid-divider" ng-controller='TopController'  >
        <div class="col-sm-2" >
          <uib-tabset active="activePill" vertical="true" type="pills"  >
            <uib-tab ng-repeat="mod in api.modules" heading="{{mod.name}}" >
              <div class="col-sm-5" style="font-size:2em; border-bottom:1px solid #ecf0f1;">
                {{mod.name}}</div>
            </uib-tab>
          </uib-tabset>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Controller

```
app.controller("TopController", function($scope){
    $scope.api = details;
});

var details = {
  root_url : "http://abc/",
  modules : [{
    name : "Content",
      methods : [{
            name : "Service List",
            method : "GET",
            headers : [{
                key : "Content-Type",
                value : "application/json"
              },{
                key : "access_token",
                value : "(String)"
              }
            ],request : "",
            response : {
              "status" : "(Boolean)",
              "code" : "(Integer)"
            }
          }
            ]
        },{
      name : "Payments",
      methods : [{
          name : "Wallets",
          method : "GET",
          headers : [{
              key : "Content-Type",
              value : "application/json"
            },{
              key : "token",
              value : "(String)"
            }
          ],
          request : "",
          response : {
            "status" : "(Boolean)",
            "code" : "(Integer)"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    ]
};
```

Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6aTqtJD1bjPB18do1Ovr?p=preview)

but i want to display selected values on green color area.[like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/jZkJ6XY3cVTolOIK2v6t?p=preview)

Comment: can you post your full code than it is easy to solve.

Comment: I have edited my post.i just want <div class="col-sm-5"> outside to <div class="col-sm-2" > . like this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/jZkJ6XY3cVTolOIK2v6t?p=preview) to show selected values on green color area

Comment: an answer to this would have been so helpful for me right now! I just encountered all of the issues bs4 has with angular1- and am banging my head against a wall for allowing nuget to influence my angular choice
.......
its funny, because the whole usefulness of tab pills relies on this